# What does an "All" nested group do in a "Match All" Smart Playlist?

Tags: itunes, logic, smart-playlist

When creating a Smart Playlist, what does placing a "**All** of the following are true" nested group when the playlist is set to "Match **all** of the following rules"?

[image]

I've tried reading through it logically a few times, and I always end up with it not actually contributing to the flow of the smart playlist. If all the items in the nested group have to be true, and all the items directly under parent must be true, it seems that this configuration would only serve as a way to group similar items to a user's preference.

Is there a logical precedence that I am missing where having a "match all" nested group on the first level of a "match all" smart playlist makes sense?

Comment: How did you create that nested 'all' in the first place? I can't make it do that.

Comment: @Tetsujin, hold down the `option` key and click the `+` button (which will have changed to a `...` button).

Answer (score 1):

It appears to simply use Logical AND if you stack like that

eg

[image]

vs

[image]

Using Any switches it to using Logical OR, so you could, with a bit of juggling get a combination of the two, AND & OR

*Edit -* ***I found an example***

[image]